# QM: Why is there a minus sign on the Energy operator when using complex conjugate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, complex-numbers

I understand how they get the first equation. But I have no idea why there is a minus sign on the second equation:
[image]

This is from a derivation for the probability density current found here: http://www.physics.ucdavis.edu/Classes/Physics115A/probcur.pdf

Comment: It's just the complex conjugate of the entire equation. $V$ is a real potential so it isn't affected, but $\psi \rightarrow \psi^*$ and $i \rightarrow -i$.

Comment: Ahaa I see! Thank you! You take the complex conjugate of the entire first equation.

Comment: But why do you not just use the operators $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{E}$ on the complex conjugate, $\psi^{*}$. Why do you have to do it this way where you use those operators on the normal form and then take the complex conjugate?

Comment: It is **not** the case that $H = \mathrm{i}\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ as abstract operators (because they act on different spaces, for one). Also, there is no difference between $\hat{H}$ and $\hat{E}$, I don't understand what you are asking in your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [bra-ket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation), we have

$$\hat H |\psi(t)\rangle = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t)\rangle $$

The [Hermitian conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Hermitian_conjugation) of this equation is

$$\langle\psi(t)|\hat H^\dagger =  -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle\psi(t)|$$

But $\hat H$ is self-adjoint thus

$$\langle\psi(t)|\hat H =  -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle\psi(t)|$$

Project onto the position basis

$$\langle\psi(t)|\hat H|x\rangle =  -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \langle\psi(t)|x\rangle$$

yielding

$$\hat H \psi^*(x,t) = -i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi^*(x,t)$$

---

As an aside, it is **not** the case that

$$\hat E = i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$

since the operator $i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$  does not operate on the state space and, thus, cannot be associated with an observable.

Rather, it operates on the ket (or bra) valued *function* of the time parameter $t$.  Consider an arbitrary ket (state)

$$|\psi\rangle$$

Now, multiply this ket by some function of time

$$f(t)\;|\psi\rangle = |\psi(t)\rangle$$

Then

$$i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\;|\psi(t)\rangle = i\hbar \dot f(t)\; |\psi\rangle$$

Comment: +1 for answering and because I learned a bunch of stuff not related to the original question from the asides.